# Get Cumulative Won Amount for Each and Every Month

Tags: apex, trigger, workflow, process-builder, formula-field

I have created a Custom Object called Budget which have lookup with Opportunity. Budget_c lookup field update by Process builder to update Budget month as per Opportunity close date.
Like, if opportunity close date in 6-Sep 2017 so process builder will update "Sep-2017" Budget in Opportunity's Budget_c lookup field.
All opportunities comes under related list on Budget page and via trigger we show Pipeline Amount and Won Amount by field on budget field.
Please find below screen shot:

[image]

Everythings are calculatind as per expectation. Only thing, I want more to update cumulative 
Won amount. Let's say if i won $100 in Jan and $50 in Feb so it should show $150 in Feb on cumulative Won field and for further months it will calculate like this till year end . 
Please help or suggest any alternative workaround to achieve it.

Comment: Write a Rollup trigger that will help's you to solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but through Rollup how can I get cumulative won amount if all opportunity related to budget object by Month. Lets say if opportunity closed in May 2017 so as per flow it related to May Budget and if opportunity close date in Sep so it relates to Sep budget.